# How to turn off ImageResizer file size limit in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms, imageresizer

I am using the MediaProcessing Module in Orchard V1.7. The source images are large TIFF files (typically up to 4928 x 3264 pixels). I have two filters set up on the image profile:

1. Resize to 200 x 200
2. Format the image to Jpg

When I display the page I get an exception logged

```
2013-08-12 16:30:55,982 [22] Orchard.MediaProcessing.Shapes.MediaShapes - An error occured while rendering shape Lightbox for image /OrchardLocal/Media/Default/Stamps%20of%20Australia/ClaytonTremlett244.tif
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimits+SizeLimitException (0x80004005): 
The dimensions of the output image (2668x3364) exceed the maximum permitted dimensions of 3200x3200.
```

ImageResizer documentation states that the default maximum file size for **output** is 3200 x 3200, but I am requesting a size of 200 x 200. I have logged this as an issue (1642).

My question is, does anyone know how to turn off the maximum file size limit check for ImageResizer when it is used through the ImageResizer managed API, as Orchard has chosen to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you resize first, then change the format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting "totalBehavior" to "ignorelimits". You can also set up totalWidth/totalHeight.
http://imageresizing.net/plugins/sizelimiting

Comment: I tried setting totalHeight/totalWidth but it had no effect and I wondered whether plugins such as sizelimiting worked when imageresizer  is called thru the api.

Comment: In the end I fixed the problem by writing a new Orchard media filter which combines both operations into one call to ImageResizer, the way it should have been done in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.config`/`app.config` add below sections (or change them if they exist):

```
<configuration>

<configSections>
....
     <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" 
requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<appSettings>
....
</appSettings>
<resizer>
     <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" defaultCommands="autorotate.default=true"/>
     <plugins>
           <add name="DiskCache" />
           <add name="SizeLimiting" />
           ....
     </plugins>
     <sizelimits totalBehavior="ignorelimits" />
</resizer>

...
```